# HTML Table taking up more than 100% of page

Tags: html, css

Firstly let me just say I know you shouldn't use tables for layout - I'm fixing someone else's code here.

I have a menu that is actually just a table with 2 rows.  The top row is a banner and the bottom row is a `<ul>` with a bunch of menu items in it.

Now for some reason this works perfectly in IE, but it doesn't work in Chrome.  The problem is that if you have more menu items than can be displayed on the page, Chrome seems to not render these items at all, where IE wraps the items and displays the extra items on the next line.  The IE behavior is what I am looking for.

```
<table id="menu_table" width="100%" style="border:collapse" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" colspan=2>
            <!-- iframe with banner -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="header>" valign="top" style="textweight:normal; " >
            <!-- ul with lots if li items -->
        </td>
        <td class="header" >
            <!-- another control -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I use the Chrome feature for 'inspect element' I can see the table rows are taking up more than 100% of the page - the highlighted area extends to the side of the screen.  If I use a div around the table I can see the div leaves a bit of margin around it, but the table inside the div still insists on rendering more than 100% it seems.

You can see this in action on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KbPF/12/) - if you view this in IE it will wrap over to the next line, if you view it in Chrome it will just disappear off the page

Comment: Do you have a live example? Its seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/8KbPF/3/

Comment: How much is the width of the iframe? If it is wider in pixels than what the 100% of the table means in pixels, than the table will grow to match it's content.

Comment: That's a really cool tool.  I think this is closer to what I've got... http://jsfiddle.net/8KbPF/11/

Comment: The iFrame is set to 100% width - I've updated the example in jsfiddle to reflect this

Comment: Funny how we now know not to use tables for layouts. When I started out in '98 Tables was the new 'in' thing and everybody knew you don't use Frames for layout. Wonder what the next 5 years will bring us :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the  `white-space: nowrap;` from the td style (from the example you posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/8KbPF/12/)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this issue in Chrome.

Using the following CSS rules

```
ul { text-decoration:none;}
li { display:inline;}
```

my list items wrap.

For a shot in the dark, try applying the style:

```
ul { white-space:normal; }
```

With normal, sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary. This is default.  [CSS White-space property @ W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp)

If I use

```
ul { white-space:nowrap; }
```

I can achieve the presentation behaviour you describe.